# R: Copying values from one to another data frame based on column value

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
data_frame1  
cmb | value | par_1 | par_2 | par_3    
 0      0.3    XXX     YYYY   ZZZ   

data_frame2 
cmb | value | par_1 | par_2 | par_3    
 1      0.333    XXX     YYYY   ZZZ   
 1      0.45   XXX     YYYY   ZZZ   
 2      10.3   XXX     YYYY   ZZZ   
 3      3.4    XXX     YYYY   ZZZ
```

where parameters `par_1`, `par_2` and `par_3` are not that relevant.

I just want to copy the values from `data_frame1` to `data_frame2` for each `cmb` value while getting the value from `cmb` (other parameters keep their values).
Expected output:

```
cmb | value | par_1 | par_2 | par_3    
 1      0.333    XXX     YYYY   ZZZ   
 1      0.45   XXX     YYYY   ZZZ
 1      0.3    XXX     YYYY   ZZZ #same value, par_1.. only cmb=1       
 2      10.3   XXX     YYYY   ZZZ
 2      0.3    XXX     YYYY   ZZZ #same value, par_1.. only cmb=2    
 3      3.4    XXX     YYYY   ZZZ 
 3      0.3    XXX     YYYY   ZZZ #same value, par_1.. only cmb=3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df2)[, rbind(.SD, subset(df1, select = -cmb)), cmb]
   cmb  value par_1 par_2 par_3
1:   1  0.333   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
2:   1  0.450   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
3:   1  0.300   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
4:   2 10.300   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
5:   2  0.300   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
6:   3  3.400   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
7:   3  0.300   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(cmb = 0L, value = 0.3, par_1 = "XXX", par_2 = "YYYY",
    par_3 = "ZZZ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L
))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(cmb = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), value = c(0.333, 0.45,
10.3, 3.4), par_1 = c("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX"), par_2 = c("YYYY",
"YYYY", "YYYY", "YYYY"), par_3 = c("ZZZ", "ZZZ", "ZZZ", "ZZZ"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R option replicating the rows in `df1` based on the unique `cmb` values in `df2`.

```
vals <- unique(df2$cmb)
df3 <- rbind(df2, transform(df1[rep(seq(nrow(df1)), length(vals)),], cmb = vals))
rownames(df3) <- NULL
df3[order(df3$cmb), ]

#  cmb  value par_1 par_2 par_3
#1   1  0.333   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
#2   1  0.450   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
#5   1  0.300   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
#3   2 10.300   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
#6   2  0.300   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
#4   3  3.400   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
#7   3  0.300   XXX  YYYY   ZZZ
```

Or implementing the same logic in `tidyverse` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  uncount(n_distinct(df2$cmb)) %>%
  mutate(cmb = unique(df2$cmb)) %>%
  bind_rows(df2) %>%
  arrange(cmb)
```